# Typeahead.js Get ID

Tags: ajax, typeahead.js

sorry but i don't find reply..

My problem is i can't retrieve the id of the selected product. The value = 0

My code :

```
$("#recherche").typeahead({
    onSelect: function(item) {
        alert(item.value); // = 0
    },
    ajax: {
        url: "/personne/autocompletation",
        displayField: "nomComplet",
        triggerLength: 1,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        preDispatch: function (query) {
            return {
                query: query
            }
        }
    },
});
```

My code HTML

```
<li class="active" data-value="0"><a href="#"><strong>C</strong>alloway</a></li>
```

Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#recherche").typeahead({
    source: function(query, process){
     $.ajax({
        url: "/personne/autocompletation",
        displayField: "nomComplet",
        triggerLength: 1,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
    });
    }
```

});